# iisnode 500.21 Handler "iisnode" has a bad module "iisnode" in its module list

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, windows-server-2008, iisnode

Getting this error on Server 2008 R2 64bit, IIS 7.5, iisnode 0.2.4.0, node.js 0.10.5 -

HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Handler "iisnode" has a bad module "iisnode" in its module list

Detailed Error Information

Module         - IIS Web Core

Notification -  ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler       -  iisnode

Error Code -    0x8007000d

Requested URL - https://sub.domain.com:443/node/helloworld/hello.js

Physical Path   - C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\helloworld\hello.js

Logon Method -  Anonymous

Logon User  - Anonymous

I have already made sure that asp.net is installed as suggested in other posts I've come across. I can access the helloworld html site at localhost/node/helloworld but when i attempt to visit the hello.js url this error occurs. The error also shows up when I attempt to use a node.js app I have written at a different URL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also run iisnode in 32 bit application pools on 64 bits systems by installing iisnode in WOW mode. Follow the instructions at https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/42#issuecomment-2791929.

Answer (score 3):

This error was caused by having "Enable 32-bit applications" set to True in the IIS Application Pool settings. Set this to False - problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Ahem, cough, also remember to actually install iisnode Doh!